# How to make Monoid instance for my type?

Tags: haskell, monoids

I have the following type:

```
data SomeType = Var String
    deriving (Eq,Show)

newtype TypeA = TypeA [(String, SomeType)]
  deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Also, I have a function:

```
fun1 :: TypeA -> TypeA -> TypeA
```

I can use this function for `mappend`.

I don't understand, how to implement Monoid interface in my case.

Comment: Side note: you *probably* should make `Sometype` a newtype as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have `fun1`, just add an instance:

```
instance Monoid TypeA where
   mempty = .... -- fill this with the neutral element
   mappend = fun1
```

Probably, you want `mempty = TypeA []`.

Comment: @David You must also verify that `fun1` is associative for it to be a correct Monoid instance.